# How to detect DOM mutation in a UIWebview?

Tags: ios, dom, uiwebview, mutation-events

Is there a good way to detect changes made by a script to the DOM ? Mutation observers don't seem to be available for Webkit on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

I think [DOM mutation events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Events/Mutation_events) are available in Mobile Safari but may not be forever since they are deprecated and replaced by mutation observers. Therefore I'd suggest using mutation observers where possible and falling back to DOM mutation events.